# Error handling in Swift AWSPolly

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-polly

Every example of AWSPolly I can find says:
// Again, we ignore the errors in the example.

For example:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/Polly-Sample/Swift/PollySample/ViewController.swift

I cannot figure out how to handle the errors. What if internet service drops out and Polly can't be accessed. I'd like to use the internal voice. But I can't figure out.

I checked:
 awsTask.isCanceled || awsTask.isFaulted

But neither of them are true if Internet service is not available.

Comment: any solution you found?